invalid output constraint in asm
I am trying to make an operating system in C. I get these errors when i compile the scripts:

gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -Wall -Wextra -ffreestanding -O2 -Iinclude -c src/io.c -o src/io.o
src/io.c:8:44: error: invalid input constraint 'a' in asm
    __asm__ __volatile__("outb %0, %1" : : "a"(value), "Nd"(port));
                                           ^
src/io.c:13:41: error: invalid output constraint '=a' in asm
    __asm__ __volatile__("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(ret) : "Nd"(port));
                                        ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [src/io.o] Error 1


This is my full code for it:
#include "io.h"
#include <stdarg.h>

// Function declaration
void itoa(char* buf, int value, int base);

void outb(unsigned short port, unsigned char value) {
    __asm__ __volatile__("outb %0, %1" : : "a"(value), "Nd"(port));
}

unsigned char inb(unsigned short port) {
    unsigned char ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(ret) : "Nd"(port));
    return ret;
}

void printf(const char* format, ...) {
    char** arg = (char**)&format;
    int c;
    char buf[20];

    arg++;

    while ((c = *format++) != 0) {
        if (c != '%') {
            outb(0xE9, c);
        } else {
            char* p;

            c = *format++;
            switch (c) {
            case 'd':
            case 'u':
            case 'x':
                itoa(buf, *((int*)arg++), c == 'd' ? 10 : (c == 'x' ? 16 : 10));
                p = buf;
                goto string;
                break;

            case 's':
                p = *arg++;
                if (!p) {
                    p = "(null)";
                }

string:
                while (*p) {
                    outb(0xE9, *p++);
                }
                break;

            default:
                outb(0xE9, '%');
                outb(0xE9, c);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void gets(char* buffer) {
    char* buf_ptr = buffer;
    while (1) {
        char c = inb(0x60);  // Read keyboard input
        if (c == '\n') {
            *buf_ptr = '\0';
            return;
        } else {
            *buf_ptr++ = c;
            outb(0xE9, c); // Echo character
        }
    }
}

// Definition of itoa
void itoa(char* buf, int value, int base) {
    char* ptr = buf;
    char* ptr1 = buf;
    char tmp_char;
    int tmp_value;

    if (base < 2 || base > 36) {
        *buf = '\0';
        return;
    }

    do {
        tmp_value = value;
        value /= base;
        *ptr++ = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                 [35 + (tmp_value - value * base)];
    } while (value);

    if (tmp_value < 0 && base == 10) *ptr++ = '-';

    *ptr-- = '\0';
    while (ptr1 < ptr) {
        tmp_char = *ptr;
        *ptr-- = *ptr1;
        *ptr1++ = tmp_char;
    }
}


I tried multiple diffrent constraints but it didn't work. I am making the kernel here and compiling it to kernel.bin
I have an makefile which runs the commands when i run "make":
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJS = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -m32 -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -Wall -Wextra -ffreestanding -O2 -Iinclude

all: kernel.bin

kernel.bin: $(OBJS)
    ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f src/*.o kernel.bin


What this constraint is supposed to be? Here is documentation of inline asm constraints:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html and I can't find the 'a' one there.

I do see it is defined for 68000/68020, but you are compiling for i386.

"a" is defined as a machine constraint for the x86 family, which makes it quite odd that the compiler is rejecting it.  It's almost like you're using an ARM compiler or something to compile this code?  That line isn't likely to work anywhere except x86, so if you're building for some other platform, that's never going to work.
